# How to output full list of comments under each post from mySQL DB?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have been working on extracting database content from WordPress blog to display onto an external site.  Basically, I currently have a page on my site which grabs all the blog posts such as blog title, date, and blog content from my WordPress database and displays them in descending order.

I would now like to show comments I approve for each post. I have not done much programming in quite a bit of time so perhaps I am missing some basic concepts here. I have listed my select query that I run in the beginning of the php to grab the content I need from tables `wp_posts` and `wp_comments`.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_comments
          LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_posts 
          ON wp_comments.comment_post_ID = wp_posts.ID
          WHERE
            comment_approved = '1' AND
            comment_type = ''
          ORDER BY post_date DESC
          LIMIT 10";

$query_result = mysql_query($query);
$num_rows = mysql_numrows($query_result);
```

I then use a for loop as shown below.

```
<?php  

//start a loop that starts $i at 0, and make increase until it's at the number of rows  
for($i=0; $i< $num_rows; $i++){   

    //assign data to variables, $i is the row number, which increases with each run of the loop  
    $blog_permalink = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "post_name");
    $blog_date = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "post_date");  
    $blog_title = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "post_title");  
    $blog_content = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "post_content");  
    $blog_permalink = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "post_name");
    $blog_comment = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "comment_content");
    $blog_comment_author = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "comment_author");
    $blog_comment_date = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "comment_date");

    //format date  
    $blog_date = strtotime($blog_date);  
    $blog_date = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", $blog_date);  

    //the following HTML content will be generated on the page as many times as the loop runs.   
?>  

</body>  
<div class="post"></div>  

       <span class="date"> <b><?php echo $blog_date; ?>:</b></code></span><br /><hr />   

        <b><?php echo $blog_title; ?></b> <br /><br />

        <?php echo $blog_content; ?> <br /> <br />

        <b><span>Comments</span></b> <br />
        <?php echo $blog_comment_date; ?> <br />
        <?php echo $blog_comment_author; ?> <br />  
        <?php echo $blog_comment; ?> <br /><br />
```

My code is currently displaying blog posts with comments. However, instead of showing all 5 comments under a single post, it is shown the blog post 5 times with a different comment in each instance of that post.

I have tried some conditional if statements within this for loop for displaying all comments under a single post but have been unsuccessful. Ideally, I would like to create a condition like, if `post_title` table has `comment_count` greater than zero, display all comments under that post from `comment_content` table. Any feedback or helpful tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `JOIN`s work like that, you get the left table on each row joined with the right table's each matching row (that many times as the right tables matching row count).  You will have to handle this programmatically or fetch the comments in a different result set without the join

Answer (score 0):

I believe there should be two queries to limit amount for data to fetch, in first query we should find last ten post having comments, and in second fetch comments by it's parent id and add it to array, here is example:

```
$posts = array();

$SQL = "SELECT p.ID AS post_id, p.post_date, p.post_title, Count(c.comment_ID) AS total
FROM wp_posts AS p
INNER JOIN wp_comments AS c ON p.ID = c.comment_post_ID
WHERE c.comment_approved = 1 AND c.comment_type = ''
GROUP BY p.ID, p.post_date, p.post_title
HAVING total > 0
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
LIMIT 10";

$result = mysql_query($SQL);

if(mysql_numrows($result))
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        //create empty array for comments
        $row['comments'] = array();

        $posts[$row['post_id']] = $row;
    }
}

mysql_free_result($result);

//check if there is any posts with comments
if($posts)
{
    //prepare post ids for IN statement
    $ids = implode(', ', array_keys($posts));

    $SQL2 = "SELECT c.* 
    FROM wp_comments AS c
    WHERE c.comment_approved = 1 AND c.comment_type = '' AND c.comment_post_ID IN ({$ids})";

    $result = mysql_query($SQL2);

    if (mysql_numrows($result))
    {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            //assign comments to posts
            $posts[$row['comment_post_id']]['comments'][] = $row;
        }
    }

    mysql_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed feedback Nazariy. I will try to apply the same concepts as your example and let you know my outcome.